# ( sqlfiddle ) Not returning all the rows from the left table

Tags: php, mysql, database

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41cf8/1

I actually expect it to return something like this

```
firstname - chuck
lastname - null
```

But it returning me only firstname rows

how i can modify it to return lastname with null value as well ?

Thank You

Comment: Plz don't get confuse with the key_parent field as it have nothing to do with users_meta table

Comment: see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41cf8/15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to move the `AND users_meta.meta_user_id = 1` from the WHERE clause into the JOIN clause.

In the WHERE clause, it limits the returned rows. In JOIN, it limits only the JOINed rows, and since you are using LEFT join, you'll still get last name.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation, I read that LEFT join should return all the rows from the left table ( and because of this had been scratching my head since yesterday ) but didn't know about the difference of using condition in Where and Join :)